# set proxyHost in android studio for gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to sync gradle with jcenter() but I have to set proxy in gradle.properties 
if I set systemProp.http.proxyHost= www.somehost.org it stuck but when I set to 127.0.0.1 it  syncs and I dont know why ???

Comment: update your logcat,msg or built gradle

Comment: Nothing special in my app when I create the new project in android studio 2.1 It wont sync unless I set proxy in gradle.properties and if I set systemProp.http.proxyHost= 127.0.0.1 it will sync and not sync by www.somehost.org

Comment: how can I set something default in android studio that whenever create new project sync without any problem?

Comment: disable your proxy like my ans

Answer (score 0):

press Ctrl+Alt+S and open setting window and disable your proxy like below picture
may be its not create any problem creating new project

[image: proxy]

Comment: thanks for your response but it is disable by default.but just sync by mavencentrall I should jcenter to mavencentral or set proxy in gradle.properties